# Looking for an endpoint to retrieve warning letters

Tags: data-request, openfda

You can search for warning letters https://www.fda.gov/inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/compliance-actions-and-activities/warning-letters

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an endpoint for this specific enforcement data exposed by open FDA.  The link you posted allows the data to be exported to Excel format.  Does this work for your use case?

Comment: It will work for some analysis, but I was really hoping for an endpoint with current data I could expect to be updated at some regular interval.

Comment: An alternative might be an Inspection Citation Dataset available via an endpoint.